# Could "shingled" mean "pebbly"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, british-english, transatlantic-differences

One of the definition of *shingle* is

> a mass of small rounded pebbles, especially on a seashore.

You can say

> a shingle beach

(more common usage in UK than US perhaps)

Is it also correct English to say

> a shingled beach

Comment: To me, *shingle* is pebbles about the size of a pea - the main type is often called "pea shingle". It's used to cover felt roofs (primarily protecting underlying felt/bitumen from direct sun), and for [french drains](http://www.mybuilder.com/questions/v/9801/french-drain-vs-pea-shingle) in the garden. Roofs are *shingled* because the shingles have been specifically *put there*. Beaches just ***are*** "shingle" (the past participle is probably out-of-place, since no-one usually put any shingle there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You will please note that *shingle* makes no appearance in the normative sequence that geologists use when classifying grain size. Running from smallest to largest, [that sequence is 1=clay, 2=silt, 3=sand, 4=gravel, 5=pebble, 6=cobble, 7=boulder](http://www.lyvemedia.com/delta/grade/2/pebbles_sand_and_silt/investigation_2/pebbles_inv2_background.html). The Wentworth scale is probably the most commonly used system for formally mapping precise diameters to English words/names, although [ISO 14688-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_size) has more nuanced stages than Wentworth.

Comment: @tchrist: The particular terms used in that scale certainly don't define "English as she is spoke". I feel that much more relevant to this current context is that AmE has a completely different word ***shingle*** used in relation to roofing (previously unknown to me, but which I now know essentially means *overlapping tile*, as opposed to *small rounded pebble*.

Comment: @tchrist I'm with FF, The Wentworth scale is American so Pea Gravel might be similar in the US. Pea shingle is a standard building contractor size (too small for French drains I'd suggest) but none the less a well known term.  Both are naturally smooth stones as opposed to crushed rock which is manually (mechanically) broken into sizes.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you said 'shingled beach' it would carry an implication that the shingle had been put there by humankind. But if you say 'shingle beach' it does not carry that message. In Britain we do not usually say 'pebbly beach' but sometimes you hear 'stony beach'.

**Later edit**

I am veering back to 'pebble-beach', having read others'comments. I think I was thrown off course by the word 'pebbly', which I do not recall hearing. It is interesting that the Brighton tourist office describes their beach as a 'pebble-beach'.

http://www.visitbrighton.com/things-to-do/beach-life

Comment: But not 'stoned beach'.

Comment: Have a look at [this BrE NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stony+beach%2Cstoney+beach%2Cshingle+beach%2Cshingled+beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstony%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstoney%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0), and compare it to the...

Comment: [AmE version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stony+beach%2Cstoney+beach%2Cshingle+beach%2Cshingled+beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstony%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstoney%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0). I think these strongly suggest that it's ***Americans*** who tend not to use ***shingle beach*** so much, and that hardly anyone uses ***shingled*** in this context - it's more for *flat* (felted) roofs, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Before reading these posts here, I am nearly certain I’d never before heard *shingle beach* in my entire life. (That said, I suppose it ***might*** have come up visiting Brighton for a day back when I was living in Wimbledon some quarter-century ago, but if so, all such memory has long ago disappeared.)  In contrast, saying a *pebble beach* is commonplace hereabouts. Adding *-y* to make *pebbly beach* now sounds like baby-talk, but apparently it was the more common formulation under Victoria.  A *rocky beach* doesn’t sound like baby-talk, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting! But when the incidence of 'shingle beach' fell dramatically in the early 1960s, I wonder what replaced it? Clearly not 'stony beach'. Besides there is a difference between shingle and stones. I don't think of Brighton beach, for example, as being shingle.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I am veering back to 'pebble-beach', perhaps like you having been thrown off the scent by the word 'pebbly', which I do not recall hearing. It is interesting that the Brighton tourist office describes their beach as a 'pebble-beach'. So armed with that I will edit my answer. http://www.visitbrighton.com/things-to-do/beach-life

Comment: @WS2 Chesil, Dungeness, Slapton - all shingle beaches. ( I agree that shingled is not the term).

Comment: @Frank But they, at least Slapton and Chesil, I don't know Dungeness, are rather different to Brighton. In fact isn't the first known as 'Slapton Sands'. Isn't it a smaller kind of pea- shingle?

Comment: Wikipedia lists Brighton amongst its examples for the [Shingle beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingle_beach) article. I'd certainly class it as a shingle beach. In my experience (I live just a few miles from Brighton and visit from time to time) the average size of the stones at Brighton is around a 5 cm diameter.

Comment: @WS2 All three are graded from one end of the beach to the other. at one end Slapton is (was) almost sandy. Sand banks (or shingle banks) under water are generally called 'Shingles'; Margate and IOW  have them.

Comment: @tobyink But 5cm diameter isn't 'shingle' is it? To my mind they are 'pebbles'. That is my point. The 'shingle' we have in front of our house is, I think I am right in saying, average 0.25cm.

Comment: Looking at Google images for things like "shingle pebble" or "shingle beach" is probably a reasonable way of gauging what most people regard as a shingle. It's not always easy to judge size from the photos unless there's something else in the photo to compare them with, but many of the pictures seem consistent with the shingles on Brighton beach.

Comment: I'd say that an average of around 0.25 cm is somewhere between gravel and grit.

Comment: From growing up near Brighton, I would say that in the beach context "shingle" is a subset of "pebbles". "Shingle" is appropriate when the beach has fairly consistently sized small pebbles. Or we might use it for the mass of such small pebbles in which you find all the other stuff (larger pebbles, seaweed, shells, bits of plastic, used condoms, etc). So in Brighton for example there are areas where the beach is "just shingle" and others where there are more large pebbles along with the shingle. People would understand if you said something like "it gets more 'shingley' near the waterline".

Comment: @Rupe I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'subset', but I am in agreement with your description of Brighton beach. But it seems to confirm to me that pebbles are pebbles and shingle is shingle. And they are two different things.

Comment: @tobyink It was sold to us as 'pea-shingle'. Previously we had av 0.5cm, but we felt that other peoples' 0.25 looked more attractive. (Grass on other side always greener?). I do prefer the look of the 0.25, but the trouble is that at that size it sticks in the soles of your shoes and one tends to carry it in the house, to the perennial complaint of my wife.

Comment: @WS2 By subset I mean that a shingle is made of pebbles, but just the smaller ones. A shingle beach is always a pebble beach, but not the other way round. It depends on how much it's dominated by the smaller stuff and there's not a precise line. But I'm just talking about my experience of how people use the words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth re *stoned beach*. I feel sure it's that too after the pubs turn out.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary defines "shingled" as "Covered or tiled with shingles; Overlapping like tiles or shingles; (Of hair) cut in a shingle; (of a person) having the hair so cut". To describe a beach covered in shingle you'd be safe saying "a shingle beach".

Comment: Quite so. (See also my comment to Josh61 above.)

Answer (score 1):

[Shingle beach](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingle_beach) :

> is a beach which is armoured with pebbles or small- to medium-sized cobbles (as opposed to fine sand). Typically, the stone composition may grade from characteristic sizes ranging from two to 200 mm.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shingle%20beach%2Cshingled%20beach%2Cpebbly%20beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpebbly%20beach%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'pebbly beach' is more common in AmE while [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shingle%20beach%2Cshingled%20beach%2Cpebbly%20beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpebbly%20beach%3B%2Cc0) 'shingle beach ' is more common in BrE.

Shingled beach is not a common definition and it suggests the idea of a beach that has been shingled for some specific  purpose rather than a natural one.

Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingle_beach

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shingled+beach%2Cshingle+beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'shingled beach' **is** used, doubtless with the same meaning as, but far less commonly than, 'shingle beach'. However, I can't find a dictionary that licenses 'shingled' for the gravel sense.

Comment: Yes, as I said it is less common than the other two definitions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- I ran the same  Ngram, but noticed that while there are legitimate uses of "shingled beach" the majority of the instances are followed by "house" or "cottage" making the use even less frequent than it might appear.

Comment: Ah. Your statement '[These] Ngram[s show] that 'shingle beach' is more common in BrE while 'pebbly beach' is more common in AmE.' is incorrect. They don't address BrE. They **do** strongly suggest that 'shingled beach' is less common than 'shingle beach' in the US.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=QVPKelUqgxwC&pg=PA111&dq=%22shingled+beach%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nmfdU5qfH8_0oASg_YDoDA&ved=0CGkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22shingled%20beach%22&f=false

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - pls have a look at the Ngram link in my answer. It just shows the difference I am talking about.

Comment: The three graphs are from their American English corpus.

Comment: Yes!!! Just click on the 'British English' button and you'll get a different set of graphs with the 'shingle beach' on top!!

Comment: Then link to those correctly!

Comment: [See here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pebbly+beach%2Cpebble+beach%2Cpebbled+beach%2Cshingly+beach%2Cshingle+beach%2Cshingled+beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpebbly%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpebble%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpebbled%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingly%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingle%20beach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshingled%20beach%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Josh61 @EdwinAshworth - Where 'shingled beach' is followed immediately by 'house' or 'cottage', the reference will almost always be to *roof shingles* (as opposed to *roof tiles*, for instance). I Googled for images of "shingled beach" and found pictures of houses/roofs outnumbering those depicting beaches at a ratio of circa 20:1. This is in line with the fact that none of the dictionaries you looked in, Edwin, equated 'shingled' with 'gravel'. In the US, asphalt or wood *roof slates* (as one would usually term them in Britain) are generally referred to as *shingles*.

Comment: @Erik Kowal The man who says he's had too many shingles may be seeing double.

Answer (score 1):

The word "shingle" seems to have two distinct meanings:

It generally referres to flat stones or building materials that comes in flat pieces.

The meaning you use, "mass of small rounded pebbles" of a "shingle beach" is special in that it is describing round objects.

If it is used in a varied way, like "shingled beach", the association with the special meaning breaks. For example, I would assume that a "shingled beach" has flat stones, like a "shingled roof".