# shingle and scree

Tags: meaning, differences

I have recently learned that shingle is used to describe a mass of small round pebbles, as in a 'shingle beach'. There is a discussion this site two years ago [about shingle vs shingled vs pebbly](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/188467/55623), ehgo. However, a word that I would use to describe a pile of pebbles is 'scree'. How does scree compare to shingle? Is it mountains vs beaches? or jagged vs rounded? Any ideas?

Comment: The difference is the weathering. Scree is basically small fallen or slid rocks, usually collected in a draw and fanning at the base of the slope. It is mostly small stuff, and it can contain a lot of fines or dirt. Shingle is small stones weathered by waves. Going up in size, you have cobble and talus, respectively.

Comment: @PhilSweet You should make that an answer

Comment: @PhilSweet (and Tobias) but note that in NZ 'shingle' also denotes "loose angular stones in mountain country", and so in NZ 'shingle slide' and 'shingle-slip' are descriptive of what is in other dialects a 'scree slope' (a slope covered with loose angular stones).

Comment: Which is why I am reluctant to convert my comment into an answer. I don't think shingle is used much at all in the US, even for beaches. And shingle beaches aren't all that common here. And these aren't technical terms in geology like pebble, cobble, or boulder. To a mountaineer, scree is the sort of stuff you can glissade down and talus is the sort of stuff that you can't.

Comment: @PhilSweet, I think what you've provided so far amounts to an excellent answer. The dialectal variations are icing...frosting...on the cake. The frosting...icing is important, true, but it needn't cover the whole cake, and it definitely shouldn't be so thick as to overwhelm the cake.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is the weathering. Scree is basically small fallen or slid rocks, usually collected in a draw and fanning at the base of the slope. It is mostly small stuff, and it can contain a lot of fines or dirt. Shingle is small stones weathered by waves. Going up in size, you have cobble and talus, respectively.

Shingle and Scree aren't really technical terms and you won't find concise definitions in geological dictionaries (I looked).